# Test UrlMapping Paths for Resource Controllers

Tags: grails, grails-controller

In Grails 2.3 and above, there is now the concept of a resource controller. However, they do not seem to work with the `assertUrlMappings` concepts.

```
/foo (resources:"foo")
```

Then in the `url-mappings-report` the following appears:

```
Controller: foo
|   GET    | /foo            | Action: index  
|   GET    | /foo/create    | Action: create                                 
|   POST   | /foo            | Action: save   
|   GET    | /foo/${id}      | Action: show   
|   GET    | /foo/${id}/edit | Action: edit   
|   PUT    | /foo/${id}      | Action: update 
|  PATCH   | /foo/${id}      | Action: patch  
|  DELETE  | /foo/${id}      | Action: delete
```

However, in the following file, the urls cannot be tested:

```
@TestFor(UrlMappings)
@Mock(FooController)
class FooURIReverseMappingsSpec extends Specification {

    def "Ensure basic mapping operations for Foo uris"() {
        expect:
        assertUrlMapping(url, controller: expectCtrl, action: expectAction) {
            id = expectId
        }
        where:
        url |   expectCtrl  | expectAction | expectId
        // Not sure why, but the resource controller generation url test does not find the real 'Foos' url
        '/foo/123'|'foo'|'show'|'123'
    }
}
```

Then WITHOUT the default action url $controller/$action/$id (which would match `foo/show/123`)  the test cannot find the generated url.

The generated error is:
   **junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: url '/foo/123' did not match any mappings**

Is there a way to test the resource urls?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is over 5 years old, but for future reference, the issue likely was the same as that in [this grails-core Github issue (URLMapping unit test for RESTfull service is not working)](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9065).

The issue was apparently solved by [this PR (Include request method in URL matching)](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/pull/9306/files). It looks like this fix was merged into Grails 2.5.x.